# Azure DevOps organization "failed to connect to the #### Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I’m trying to connect  an Azure DevOps organization to Azure AD. But, I’m getting the error message below:

[image]

I have checked the users, and this user has only one UPN in Azure AD and DevOps.
I searched, but I couldn’t find any solution, any help from anyone?

Answer (score 0):

According to this  [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/faq-azure-access?view=azure-devops#q-why-did-i-get-an-error-stating-that-my-organization-has-multiple-active-identities-with-the-same-upn):

> During the connect process, we map existing users to members of the Azure AD tenant, based on their UPN, which is often known as sign-in address. If we detect multiple users with the same UPN, we don't know how to map these users. This scenario occurs if a user changes their UPN to match one already existing in the organization.

The cause of this issue is that the target user has the same UPN as other user. A UPN must be unique among all security principal objects within a directory forest.

The UPN contains UPN prefix (the user account name) and a UPN suffix (a DNS domain name). For example:`someone@example.com`

You can compare the target account with other user accounts. Then you could find the duplicate UPN.

You could try to remove the duplicate one or  [change the UPN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/howto-troubleshoot-upn-changes#learn-about-upns-and-upn-changes)  as unique.